# Flickr API error when oauth

Tags: flickr

When accepting my flickr app, I get the following error message:
*"Oops! Flickr doesn't recognise the permission set."*

It seems I am not alone with this problem, see Yang and Yun's Album's on [this](http://www.flickr.com/groups/api/discuss/72157626891119797/) discussion.

Any help very much aprreciated,

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I ran to the same problem and the solution for me was to add optional "perms" parameter to the authorize request:

http://www.flickr.com/services/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=7...2&perms=write

Hope it will work for you too :)

Comment: Flickr documentation indicates that this is an optional parameter, but I cannot get it to work unless I provide it, thanks for sharing!

Comment: It worked for me too. I'm pretty sure this was optional or it was configured per application, because I had to modify the OAuth library that I have been using before without a problem.